# adding column and record in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I am working on a Crystal Report and I need to always have two records of the record been pulled from the Database. however, I am hardcoding two fields into the report. Every time there is a record the record should have a column that has a field with a 1 value and a 2 value, everytime there is a 1 then another field should be added saying '111211' and for the other record with a 2 value the other column should say '222122'. My query is pulling the studentID based on a condition however everytime there is a record a field should be added to the report creating two records one for a value of '1' and another for the value of '2'.  Is there a way to implement this in a crystal report?? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
StudentID  addedField  addedFieldTwo
5191205     1          11121        
5191205     2          222122
5191215     1          11121        
5191215     2          222122
5191891     1          11121        
5191891     2          222122
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use a `cross join` to get your results:

```
select studentid, addedfield, addedfieldtwo
from yourtable cross join 
    (select 1 as addedField, 11121 as addedFieldTwo
     union all
     select 2 as addedField, 222122 as addedFieldTwo
     ) t
order by studentid, addedfield, addedfieldtwo
```

This creates a `cartesian product` for every student record that gets returned.